# Is there a way to put Kubernetes secret value in args field of yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-secrets

I have a kubernetes yaml deployment file which accepts db username and password as arguments as shown below.

```
args:
        - "-db_host=postgres"
        - "-db_port=5432"
        - "-db_username=postgres"
        - "-db_password=postgres"
```

To hide the values of db_username and db_password I thought of using kubernetes secret kind. But to achieve that I have to make db_username and db_password as environment variables so that I can use it something like as shown below:

```
args:
        - "-db_host=postgres"
        - "-db_port=5432"
env:
        - name: db_username
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-secret
              key: db-user
        - name: db_password
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-secret
              key: db-pass
```

Is there any way we can use secret in args itself so that I don't have to do the 2nd approach.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Once you have an environment variable you can embed its value into the arguments:

```
env:
- name: MESSAGE
  value: "hello world"
command: ["/bin/echo"]
args: ["$(MESSAGE)"]
```

Or in your case:

```
args:
        - "-db_host=postgres"
        - "-db_port=5432"
        - "-db_username=$(db_username)"
        - "-db_password=$(db_password)"
env:
        - name: db_username
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-secret
              key: db-user
        - name: db_password
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: db-secret
              key: db-pass
```

The reference can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)

Comment: With the emphasize on parenthesis, i.e.: `$(VAR)` instead of accolades, i.e.: `${VAR}` as the latter will return an empty value...

Comment: never heard them called "accolades" before

Comment: @Erez key are visible to user who have login access to pod
How can we hide from all?

Comment: I have the same question as @xyz_scala, I would like to pass the secret without creating an environment variable, mainly to hide it from any other threads or processes that are started. Is it possible to do so?